# Find a minium value of a function with discrete parameters, but some combinations are invalid

Tags: constrained-optimization, discrete-optimization

I'm not a mathematician, so sorry if I miss some obvious stuff. I'm trying to develop a bot for StarCraft 2, in particular the army control for it. For every army of the enemy, I want to find the minimal possible combination of my units that will be able to defeat it.

For example, if I have 20 marines, 10 tanks, and 10 planes, I have 2000 possible combinations of those units that I have to choose from. Every unit has a supply cost, and I want to come up with the cheapest possible army that will still do the job.

I googled a bit and it looks like I could maybe use something like gradient descent with discrete inputs, but it looks like my situation is slightly more complicated. I have two functions - one that takes the army and calculates the cost (very cheap, less than 1ms), and one that takes the army and tells me if it's going to win (more expensive, maybe 100ms). So some combinations may be cheap, but irrelevant to me because they will lose.

I'm so inexperienced in this, that I'm not even sure what to google here. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Reminds me of an [assignment problem](https://mecheng.iisc.ac.in/suresh/me256/hw2019/homework1.html) from college. Also could you give a simple clear example, like how your enemies army would be and what you would have to optimize for. I understand your problem but it would be better with a more detailed example.

Comment: I'll try to give a bit more context first. I'm trying to solve the situation when the enemy's army splits into multiple chunks, and I have to also split my army to deal with each one of them.


Some units counter other units, so ideally for each chunk of the enemy's army I want to send just enough units that can win the fight in the most efficient way. This would allow me to deal with every part of their army, and go aggressive with the remainder of my own units.

Comment: For example, I see that the enemy is sending two [broodlords](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Brood_Lord_(Legacy_of_the_Void)) from the left, and a bunch of [zerglings](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Zergling_(Legacy_of_the_Void)) from the right. I have a few [vikings](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Viking_(Legacy_of_the_Void)), a couple [battlecruisers](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Battlecruiser_(Legacy_of_the_Void)), and 10 [hellions](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Hellion_(Legacy_of_the_Void)).

Comment: I want my bot to send the hellions to deal with zerglings (since they can kill them very efficiently), send vikings to kill the broodlords (broodlords cannot even attack ground, and are really slow so they cannot run away), and attack with the battlecruisers.

Comment: The complex part is that there is an unthinkable amount of possible scenarios, and the enemy can have combinations of different units in each chunk. What I want is a system that can split my army at least semi-competently.

Comment: The good news is that I have a function that can predict the outcome of a battle, given the composition of two armies. It was created using machine learning using actual battle simulations.

Comment: Okay, as far as I understand, you have a function which can predict the outcome (I assume it throws out some value) given some input variables representing your army and enemies army. As your machine learning model is trained already, would it be possible to fix the model parameters which you would've tuned to train the model and now instead tune the input variables with constraints to get a higher value of your prediction success? If this machine learning function is a continuous functions, you can maybe calculate gradients and optimise for the input variables representing your army.